# Get X and Y coordinates inside a recylcerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm having trouble retrieving the position clicked by the user, inside a recyclerView.
*What I have:*

A RecyclerView with cardView.

*What I need:*

Retrieve the coordinates X and Y, where the user clicked on this "cardView", so I can then work with some animations from there.

*
What I've tried:*

```
int[] originalPos = new int[2];
view.getLocationInWindow(originalPos);
```

That way, I conquered the position of Y, originalPos [1], but the position X, originalPos [0], always returns me 0.

I already tried to get the position clicked through a relative layout, frame layout, etc ... but it is always returned me 0 at position X.

Thank you all for the help and attention to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getLocationInWindow is intended to get the x,y of the left-top of the view.

You should use onTouchListener to get the motionevent. BUT: touchListener will return x,y based on the 0,0 of the view you are listening to, and also recognizing clicks should be done by proxing the events to a GestureRecognizer or do some ifs (DOWN + NOT MOVED + UP).

Cant you solution work in the whole view that was clicked instead of the exactly point it got touched?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solution, this perfectly suited my needs.